# Adding the number of link-neighbors in Netlogo

Tags: count, netlogo

I want to add the number of link-neighbors of a particular color a turtle in Netlogo. I did this on the to go procedure:

```
ask one-of turtles [

set num-vecinos sum [count turtles] of link-neighbors with [color = gray]
show num-vecinos
]
```

Strangely I have only one gray turlte but if I run the code I get 5. Why is it counting 5? shouldn't I be getting one? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
[count turtles]
```

is going to return the total number of turtles in the world, regardless of all your other code.

to count all the neighbor turtles that are gray, you would use

```
set num-vecinos count (link-neighbors with [color = gray])
```

the parenthesis are not strictly needed, but I think they make the code more readable.